# What's wrong with the following argument showing that $L^p$ is Banach.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

I want to show that $L^p$ is complete (assume I have everything else done). Here's my approach which is slightly different from the usual approach.

If $f_n$ is Cauchy then let $g_k$ be subsequence such that $\|g_{k+1}-g_k\|_p<\dfrac{1}{2^k}$. Then let $$f=g_1+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}g_{k+1}-g_k$$

As the name suggest, I want to show that $f_n\rightarrow f$. Now suppose that I already know that $f$ is in $L^p$, then I only need to show that $f_n$ converges to $f$.

To show that I say, for $g_n$ we have

$$\| f-g_n\|=\|(g_1+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}g_{k+1}-g_k)-g_n\|$$

But the sum is telescoping and it is equal to $g_n+\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}g_{k+1}-g_k$

and so
$$\| f-g_n\|=\|\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}g_{k+1}-g_k)\|\le \sum_{k=n}^{\infty}\|g_{k+1}-g_k)\|\le \dfrac{1}{2^n}$$

the second to last inequality is the Minkowski's inequality and continuity of the norm. So $g_n\rightarrow f$. But since $f_n$ is Cauchy, we conclude that $f_n\rightarrow f$.
I can't tell what's wrong with the argument, but I have my suspicions. First, the book does it differently and the difference is significant. Second, I can apply this argument to conclude that any functional space over any space (not necessary banach) is Banach, which sounds dubious. I would appreciate your feed back. Even more dubiously, the same argument tells me that $\|f\|= 0$

Comment: The sum in the definition of $f$ is a pointwise sum?

Comment: Don't you use the fact that this is a norm sum when you use "the Minkowski's inequality and continuity of the norm" argument?

Comment: @KeeperOfSecrets my bad.

Comment: If you define $f$ pointwisely, you need to show that such series converges (a.e.). See Claim 1 and Claim 2 in my proof.

Comment: @DannyPak-KeungChan I only need to show the series converges $L_p$. As I said, the situation is not so straightforward and I left some other functions that would help

Comment: @crystal_math Read my proof and you will know how and why.

Comment: @DannyPak-KeungChan I will and thank you for your contribution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a  complete normed linear space (i.e. a Banach sapce) $\sum \|x_n\| <\infty$ implies that $\sum x_n$ converges in the norm. Completeness of the space is essential for this. Your definition of $f$ already assumes that the space is complete since you are assuming that the series defining $f$ is convergent.

Comment: But you don't have the point-wise bound $|g_{k+1} (x)-g_k(x)| <\frac 1 {2^{k}}$.

Comment: My mistake. f converges a.e. I also said let's assume this since the book actually proves this and I agree with the proof. It's on the second part of the proof where we have differing approaches.

Answer (score 0):

Let $(X,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ be a measure space. Let $p\in[1,\infty)$.
We go to show that $L^{p}(X,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ is complete. We assume
that $L^{p}$ is a normed space and that Minkowski's inequality holds.
Hence, we are going to prove that the $L^{p}$-norm is complete.

Let $([f_{n}])_{n}\in L^{p}$ be a Cauchy sequence. For each equivalence
class $[f_{n}]$, pick a representative $f_{n}$ in an arbitrary way.
(Note that $f_{n}:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a measurable function)
Choose integers $1\leq n_{1}<n_{2}<\ldots$ such that $||f_{n_{k+1}}-f_{n_{k}}||_{p}\leq\frac{1}{2^{k}}$.
For simplicity, denote $g_{k}=f_{n_{k}}$.

Claim 1: There exists $A\in\mathcal{F}$ with $\mu(A^{c})=0$ such
that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|g_{k+1}(x)-g_{k}(x)|<\infty$ for each $x\in A$.

Proof of Claim 1: For each $K\in\mathbb{N}$, define $S_{K}:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$
by $S_{K}(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{K}|g_{k+1}(x)-g_{k}(x)|$. Clearly, $S_{K}$
is non-negative and measurable. Moreover, $S_{1}\leq S_{2}\leq\ldots$.
Let $S=\lim_{K\rightarrow\infty}S_{K}$ be defined pointwisely. Note
that $S$ may take value $+\infty$. By Minkowski's inequality, $||S_{K}||_{p}\leq\sum_{k=1}^{K}||g_{k+1}-g_{k}||_{p}\leq\sum_{k=1}^{K}\frac{1}{2^{k}}\leq1$.
That is, $\int S_{K}^{p}d\mu\leq1$. Letting $K\rightarrow\infty$
and by Monotone Convergence Theorem, we have $\int S^{p}d\mu\leq1$.
In particular, $S$ is $\mathbb{R}$-valued $\mu$-a.e. Let $A=\{x\in X\mid S(x)\in\mathbb{R}\}$,
then $\mu(A^{c})=0$ and $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|g_{k+1}(x)-g_{k}(x)|<\infty$
for each $x\in A$.

Claim 2: Let $f=g_{1}1_{A}+1_{A}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(g_{k+1}-g_{k})$
be defined pointwisely. Then $f$ is a $\mathbb{R}$-valued measurable function. Moreover, $\int|f|^{p}d\mu<\infty$.

Proof of Claim 2: If $x\in A^{c}$, then $[1_{A}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(g_{k+1}-g_{k})](x)=0$.
If $x\in A$, then $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|g_{k+1}(x)-g_{k}(x)|<\infty\Rightarrow\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}[g_{k+1}(x)-g_{k}(x)]$
converges to an element in $\mathbb{R}$ (here, we have invoked the
completeness of $\mathbb{R}$ implicitly). Therefore, $\left(1_{A}\sum_{k=1}^{K}(g_{k+1}-g_{k})\right)_{K}$
is a sequence of measurable functions which converges pointwisely
and hence the pointwise limit is $\mathbb{R}$-valued and measurable.
That is, $f$ is $\mathbb{R}$-valued and measurable. Denote $h_{K}=g_{1}1_{A}+1_{A}\sum_{k=1}^{K}(g_{k+1}-g_{k})$.
Note that $|h_{K}|^{p}\rightarrow|f|^{p}$ pointwisely. By Minkowski's
inequality, we have that $||h_{K}||_{p}\leq||g_{1}1_{A}||_{p}+||1_{A}\sum_{k=1}^{K}(g_{k+1}-g_{k})||_{p}\leq||g_{1}||_{p}+1$.
That is, $\int|h_{K}|^{p}d\mu\leq\left(1+||g_{1}||_{p}\right)^{p}$.
Letting $K\rightarrow\infty$ and by Fatou's lemma, we have that $\int|f|^{p}d\mu\leq\left(1+||g_{1}||_{p}\right)^{p}<\infty$.

Claim 3: $g_{k}\rightarrow f$ in $L^{p}$-norm.

Proof of Claim 3: For $K>k$, we have that $h_{K}-g_{k}1_{A}=1_{A}g_{K+1}-1_{A}g_{k}=1_{A}\sum_{i=k}^{K}(g_{i+1}-g_{i}).$
By Minkowski's inequality, we have that
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & \int|h_{K}-g_{k}1_{A}|^{p}d\mu\\
 & \leq & \left(\sum_{i=k}^{K}\frac{1}{2^{i}}\right)^{p}\\
 & \leq & (\frac{1}{2^{k-1}})^{p}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Since $h_{K}\rightarrow f$ pointwisely, by Fatou's lemma, we have
$\int|f-g_{k}|^{p}d\mu=\int|f-g_{k}1_{A}|^{p}d\mu\leq\liminf_{K}\int|h_{K}-g_{k}1_{A}|^{p}d\mu\leq(\frac{1}{2^{k-1}})^{p}.$
That is, $||f-g_{k}||_{p}\leq\frac{1}{2^{k-1}}$ and hence $g_{k}\rightarrow f$
in $L^{p}$.

Claim 4: $f_{n}\rightarrow f$ in $L^{p}$.

Proof of Claim 4: Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given. Choose $N$ such
that $||f_{m}-f_{n}||_{p}<\varepsilon$ whenever $m,n\geq N$. Choose
$k'$ such that $n_{k}>N$ whenever $k\geq k'$. By claim 3, there
exists $k''>k'$ such that $||g_{k}-f||_{p}<\varepsilon$ whenever
$k\geq k''$. Let $n\geq N$ be arbitrary, then $||f_{n}-f||_{p}\leq||f_{n}-f_{n_{k''}}||_{p}+||f_{n_{k''}}-f||_{p}<2\varepsilon.$
Therefore $f_{n}\rightarrow f$ in $L^{p}$-norm.

Comment: Thanks for the time you spent on this. I'll try to look at it sometime in the future. But if you are really interested in my question, one thing I would say is that it is more subtle than what I stated and I also omitted a lot of context in my original question. That's my fault, but thank you for your contribution